# TypeScript - React Native : what is the way to switch between cases in the example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

```
 const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);
  const toggleDarkMode = () => setDarkMode(previousState => !previousState);

  const [locationName, setLocationName] = useState(false);
  const toggleLocationName = () => setLocationName(previousState => !previousState);

  const [diameter, setDiameter] = useState(false);
  const toggleDiameter = () => setDiameter(previousState => !previousState);
```

how can i do a switch case with just one function in my example ?

as you can see that the "toggleFunc" appears with different names.

```
"const toggleFunc = () => setDarkMode(previousState => !previousState);"
```

```
const filterFunctions = (toggleFunc: () => void, setOfVal: any) => {
switch (setOfVal) {
case darkMode: 
 return () => setDarkMode(previousState => !previousState);
 case locationName:
        return () => setLocationName(previousState => !previousState);
 case diameter:
        return () => setDiameter(previousState => !previousState);
    }
  };
```

Comment: There's no `switch` in your code? Anyway, you can use an object like `const toggles = { dark: toggleDarkMode, loc: toggleLocationName, diam: toggleDiameter };` Now you can use a string to store the key: `let togglekey = "dark";` (or "loc" or "diam"). This way you can now do `toggles[toggleKey]();` (this is how I understood your question anyway)

Comment: i edit my code and add the switch .
can you show me how can i do it  ?

Comment: Didn't I do that in my comment? :) For `case darkMode:` to work, `darkMode` needs to be defined somewhere. If you use a string instead, you can use square brackets notation to use the string as key for an object.

Comment: Here's live example code: https://jsfiddle.net/Lcpgu0ow/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Would do it this way it's much more cleaner in my opinion

```
 const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);
 const [locationName, setLocationName] = useState(false);
 const [diameter, setDiameter] = useState(false);


 const toggles = {
    diameter: () => setDiameter(p => !p),
    darkMode: () => setDarkMode(p => !p),
    locationName: () => setLocationName(p => !p),
 }
```

then you call each function like this

`toggles.darkMode()`